# Setting the column-order of the attributetable in ArcMap programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, fields-attributes

I'm loading a feature layer to ArcMap and want to prepare the columns shown in the attribute-table. 
Aliasname and visibility I set with `ILayerFields`-Interface of the FeatureLayer by passing it to the `IFieldInfo`. But I haven't found a way to set the order of the columns.

Found out reading the column-order is possible with FindFields:

```
public virtual object FindFields { get; }
    Member of ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass
```

It gives me the column-names in choosed order. But it has only a get and not a set.

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Usually, the only way to change column order is to physically change the data source by rewriting it in the desired order. The exception to this is Query Layers, since they are based on a SELECT statement which can be altered.

Comment: @Vince This I couldn't believe, because in ArcMap in layerproperties you can change the column-order in the fields tab and the datasource will not be changed even in shape files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the right interface by searching the Object Browser of Visual Studio...

```
public virtual void SetFieldOrder(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFieldInfoSet FieldInfoSet)
Member of ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass
```